# Recover overwritten contents of text file

Tags: files, data-recovery

I deleted my file content in the file how can i recover back using timestamps is it possible 
for ex: I am having the **file1.txt**

```
cat file1.txt 
i am linux user 
i am new to linux 
i love linux
```

After sometime i later i delete the file content

```
cat file1.txt 
empty:
```

how to get back the content again in the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how you edited / deleted and how many times the content. Some editors like `gedit` creates a backup copy of file before saving with the '~' (tilde) suffix. These files  with the '~' suffix are hidden files for most of file managers (like Nautilus). So, with a little bit of luck you can recovery your lost content from these files.

Comment: Thanks but ,i don’t have gedit i am using vi editor could tell me these editor also create file in same way

Comment: @Premkumar Sorry to inform you, but by default `vi` doesn't create backup files. You can see [this guidelines](http://www.gmarks.org/vi_backups.html) about how you can make vi to store backups of the file you are editing.

Answer (score 0):

Backup file for  some text document files will be automatically created if it was opened using gedit text editor.Which was hidden and it ends with `~`.By default this text document backup option was enabled.If you dont want gedit to create any backups.Then you can disable this option from,

**Gedit-->Edit-->Preferences-->Editor**

[image]

To ensure it's presence try `ls` command after cding into the current directory.If it was located, then copy its contents to the main file by running the below command,

```
cat file1.txt~ > file1.txt
```

Comment: thanks but i don’t have GUI ,then how can i do that enabling, can i do that in command line is there any command and also i am not having gedit